# Where is os.stat() defined in CPython?

Tags: python, cpython

I've looked through the CPython sources ([Hg online here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c09f454af2c6/)), but I can't seem to find where `os.stat()` is defined. It looks like `stat` is magically a global in the `os` module (Lib/os.py, ca. line 139).

Can someone point me to the appropriate file(s)?

Comment: Looks like `posix_stat()` in Modules/posixmodule.c:2302 is exposing the `stat(2)` syscall to python, but it doesn't quite explain how it arrives in `os`. It gets added to `posix_modules` on line 10952, corresponding to "stat". These look to be exported from the module on line 11814.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like line 51 (for UNIX; there are similar lines for other platforms):

```
from posix import *
```

Tracing it back, we find out we reach that point through the return value of line 29:

```
_names = sys.builtin_module_names
```

And `posix_stat` is defined in [Modules/posixmodule.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c09f454af2c6/Modules/posixmodule.c%3a):2301, which is ultimately called by `os`:

```
static PyObject * posix_lstat(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs) // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This function is platform-dependent, and defined in one of the modules `posix`, `nt`, `os2` or `ce`.  As an example, here is the [implementation of `os.stat()` for POSIX operating systems](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c09f454af2c6/Modules/posixmodule.c#l2301).

Comment: I found that function myself. How does it end up in `os`? Thanks.

Comment: @ConradMeyer: It is imported.  There are a bunch of `from xxx import *` statements in `os.py`; the right one is selected based on platform.